# Issue with LINQ 'OR' condition when adding .ToList (or ToArray) in the end

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp-classic, lambda

Working with DB through DataContext.

Have such operation:

```
var flat = StavRealtyDb.TargetFlat
    .Where(x => true || _some condition_).ToList();
```

So, if the FIRST part of condition is **true**, the SECOND part should be **skipped** by compiler, right?
But it doesn't happens. The same problem will happen, if there would be .ToArray().

BUT, if it won't be anything like .ToList or .ToArray in the end - compiler will SKIP the second part of condition.

What is the problem? Is it normal? :)

**UPDATE**

Ok, thanks for your answers! I understood that it's normal. But the problem is that the 1st part of the condition contains: someobject == null; the second part contains: someobject.Contains().

```
.Where(x => someobject == null || someobject.Field.Contains(x.somefield))
```

So I have **ArgumentNullException** when someobject == null (my hope was that the 1st part will return true and the 2nd part WILL NOT execute). Could you advise me, how can I solve this problem?

P.S: actually, the .Where() expression is more complex:

```
.Where(x=> (part1 || part 2) && (part1 || part2) && ......)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Can you show code that *does not* behave the way you expect?

Comment: Side note: I don't believe *compiler* will skip right condition even if left part of OR is true for lambda/expressions (unlike in `if(true || _some condition_)` case ).

Comment: _What_ doesn't happen? And SQL will behave differently anyway.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: The compiler would optimize that out, but not for expression trees.

Comment: @SLaks So you are saying `Func<bool,bool> f = (x => true || !x)` optimize to just `return true` at compile time (nice if it is the case).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes.  http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayAYsAikAPAT58iAGjUaAfDABmMALwwxADxP7kAJ2CoYAH0cwAhOak5ZAX2zegAA

Comment: @SLaks thanks! (and good to know online tool that just show "IL"-based result).

Comment: How do you check whether `_some condition_` is skipped or not?

Comment: @GertArnold, it's simple! I have exception from there. The 2nd part contains such condition: someobject.Contains(smth). And the 1st part contains verification: someobject == null. So, if 1st condition is true (someobject == null), someobject in second condition is null, but calls Contains() method - it throws Exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Now I understand. But the problem is that I get ArgumentNullException. I've updated my question and explained my problem further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers so far touch some issues that play a role but don't cover the whole picture. Also, it is essential information that the second condition is a `Contains` statement. So let's say the core statement is

```
StavRealtyDb.TargetFlat.Where(x => true || someList.Contains(x.Id))
```

As said, the whole LINQ statement is an `Expression`, so the compiler doesn't apply any optimizations. So if all is well -

1. the .Net runtime succeeds in creating an expression,
2. passes it to the EF query provider,
3. the query provider translates it into SQL,
4. ADO.Net runs the SQL,
5. the database executes it, and returns a result set back to the .Net runtime,
6. the .Net runtime creates objects from the result set and returns them into `var flat`.

In this course of events, the second predicate is always *read* by the .Net runtime, irrespective of how many predicates precede it, but *evaluated* by the database if the query optimizer finds reasons to do so.

Now something's wrong: `someList` is `null`. Now the whole process comes to a halt at step 3. The query provider tries to read `someList` (in order to convert it to an `IN` clause). But, of course, that fails with a null reference.

So you have to make sure that `someList` is never null (it could be an empty list) or you could compose the `Where` condition: only if `someList` isn't null, you include the `Contains` predicate.

Comment: Thanks! Easy and fast solution (to do List empty and check for .Any()).

Answer (score 2):

You're doing `Where` on `IQueryable` and the argument is an `Expression` not a `Func`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

The `Expression` is just passed to the underlying `Where` implementation.

I found the subject interesting so I've created an example. Suppose we have following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestApplication
{
    class CompilerTest
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            Func<bool> func = () => true || Foo();
            Expression<Func<bool>> expr = () => true || Foo();
        }

        public static bool Foo()
        {
            return new Random().Next() % 2 == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

We build it (Release build) and the decompiled code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TestApplication
{
  internal class CompilerTest
  {
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private static Func<bool> CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1;

    public CompilerTest()
    {
      base.\u002Ector();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
      if (CompilerTest.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 == null)
      {
        // ISSUE: method pointer
        CompilerTest.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new Func<bool>((object) null, __methodptr(\u003CTest\u003Eb__0));
      }
      Func<bool> func = CompilerTest.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1;
      (Expression<Func<bool>>) (() => true || CompilerTest.Foo());
    }

    public static bool Foo()
    {
      return new Random().Next() % 2 == 0;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private static bool \u003CTest\u003Eb__0()
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

and if we hide compiler generated code (dotPeek option) it looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace TestApplication
{
  internal class CompilerTest
  {
    public void Test()
    {
      Func<bool> func = (Func<bool>) (() => true);
      (Expression<Func<bool>>) (() => true || CompilerTest.Foo());
    }

    public static bool Foo()
    {
      return new Random().Next() % 2 == 0;
    }
  }
}
```

As we can see the Func code specified in lambda *was* optimized (that was the real question if the compiler optimizes that). The code specified in expression was obviously not optimized (since it's an Expression so there is nothing to optimize at this point from the compiler perspective).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand. But the problem is that I get ArgumentNullException. I've updated my question and explained my problem further.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal and by-design for Linq Providers.  In this case the Linq Provider is designed to take the Where expression and turn it into Sql and execute it on the Sql Server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand. But the problem is that I get ArgumentNullException. I've updated my question and explained my problem further.

Answer (score 0):

`Where()` will return an `IQueryable<>`, which you can see as a query ready to be executed. It is, however, only *built* in the `Where()` and it will be *executed* whenever the actual data is needed - in this case, when calling `ToList()`. The query will hold the OR and thus it is completely normal behaviour that it is not short circuited because it is simply not executed within the `Where()`.

If you'd like to understand it better, try splitting it up and put a breakpoint at the `Where()`.

```
var query = StavRealtyDb.TargetFlat.Where(x => true || _some condition_);
var actualData = query.ToList();
```

When hovering over `query` while debugging, you will notice it being an actual query like

```
SELECT `Extent1`....
```

And after calling `ToList()`, you will notice that the data is retrieved from the database and put in a `List`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand. But the problem is that I get ArgumentNullException. I've updated my question and explained my problem further.